# How would you visualize Levy metric?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_metric):

> Let $F, G : \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ be two cumulative distribution functions. Define the Lévy distance between them to be
>   :$$L(F, G) := \inf \{ \varepsilon > 0 | F(x - \varepsilon) - \varepsilon \leq G(x) \leq F(x + \varepsilon) + \varepsilon \mathrm{\,for\,all\,} x \in \mathbb{R} \}.$$
>
> Intuitively, if between the graphs of $F$ and $G$ one inscribes squares with sides parallel to the coordinate axes (at points of discontinuity of a graph vertical segments are added), then the side-length of the largest such square is equal to $L$($F$, $G$).

I was wondering how to picture "between the graphs of $F$ and $G$ one inscribes squares with sides parallel to the coordinate axes (at points of discontinuity of a graph vertical segments are added)"?

Why "the side-length of the largest such square is equal to $L$($F$, $G$)"?

How is the Levy metric a special case of [the Lévy–Prokhorov metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric)?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4):

For the picture, (first assuming that both $F$ and $G$ are continuous) for every $x$, I would start out from the point $P_G(x):=(x,G(x))$ on the graph of $G$ and draw both lines from that with tangents $\pm45^\circ$. Where these lines meet the graph of $F$ will determine the *square* on the picture around $P_G(x)$ which meets the graph of $F$ on both left and right side.

With this property we roll these squares around $P_G(x)$ for each $x$ and now have to take the *supremum* of their side lengths, because that will be the infimum of the $\varepsilon$'s that satisfy the criterium for all $x$.

---

For the other question, a distribution function $F:\Bbb R\to [0,1]$ determines a Borel measure $\mu_F$ on $\Bbb R$, defined as
$$\mu_F((a,b]):=F(b)-F(a) \ . $$

Comment: Thanks! (1) I think I still don't get the picture. From the very beginning, I fail. (2) "for the other question", is it the question "how is a levy distribution a special case of L-P metric"? Do Levy metric and L-P metric induce the same topology?

Comment: L-P metric is a metric among the (probability) *measures* on a space (now on $\Bbb R$), while the Levy metric is a metric rather among the (distribution) *functions*. The connection is that $$d_{L\text{-}P}(\mu_F,\mu_G)=d_{Levy}(F,G)\ .$$
In that sense, as they are equal, of course generate the same topology.

Comment: For (1), you actually have to *draw* it. For each $x$ I imagined the least square with center $(x,G(x))$ such that both its left and right side segment meets the graph of $F$ (or something like that). Try to *draw* the situation $F(x - \varepsilon) - \varepsilon \leq G(x) \leq F(x + \varepsilon) + \varepsilon$

Comment: Thanks! I imagine a square centered as $(x, G(x))$ meets $F(x-\epsilon)-\epsilon$ at its right-down corner and meets $F(x+\epsilon)+\epsilon$ at its left-up corner? Is that the only case of meeting?

Comment: I didn't understand this explanation but [I found this explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/358095/844467) clear. I still don't understand the $45^°$ in the current post ($\pm 45^°$ from a vertical line?) I interpret "roll these squares around $P_G(x)$" rather as "slide these squares along $P_G(x)$".

Answer (score 1):

- In the domain of $x$ where $G(x)\geqslant F(x)$, it is obviuous that $G(x)\geqslant F(x-\varepsilon)-\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.
  See following figure for the inscribes square with side length $r$ bwtween $F$ and $G$. The square touches the point $(x_0,G(x_0))$ and
  $
  G(x_0)=F(x_0+r)+r.
  $
  For any $\tilde{r}>r$, we have
  $$G(x_0)< F(x_0+\tilde{r})+\tilde{r}.\tag{*}$$

[image]

- In the domain of $x$ where $F(x)\geqslant G(x)$, it is obviuous that $G(x)\geqslant F(x+\varepsilon)+\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.
  See following figure for the inscribes square bwtween $F$ and $G$. The square touches the point $(x_0,G(x_0))$ and
  $
  G(x_0)=F(x_0-r)-r.
  $
  For any $\tilde{r}>r$, we have
  $$G(x_0)> F(x_0+\tilde{r})+\tilde{r}.\tag{**}$$

[image]

- Equations (*) and (**) explain why we take $\inf_{\varepsilon>0}$ in the definition of Levy metric.
- There are infinitely many such inscribes squares, and the side-length of the **largest such square** is equal to the Levy's metric.